# Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set

Tags: amp-html

Using guide https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/amp-cors-requests#testing-cors-in-amp to test a form in the AMP cache i get the following error in the console but dont get it on the domain.

> Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Form

```
<form method="post" class="p2 i-amphtml-form" action- 
xhr="https://******.co.uk/form_post.php" target="_top" 
novalidate="">
<div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative m0 p0 mb3">
<input type="text" class="block border-none p0 m0" name="name" 
placeholder="name ..." required="">    
    <input type="email" class="block border-none p0 m0" name="email" 
placeholder="email ..." required=""></div>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="ampstart-btn caps">
 <div submit-success="">
<template type="amp-mustache">
  Success! 
</template>
</div>
<div submit-error="">
<template type="amp-mustache">
  Error!
</template>
</div>
</form>
```

form_post.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $to = "*******.co.uk";
$subject = "Website Enquiry";
$txt = $name;
    $headers = array(
'From: ' . $email . '' ,
'Reply-To: ' . $email . '' ,
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() ,
'MIME-Version: 1.0' ,
'Content-type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"' 
 );
  $headers = implode( "\r\n" , $headers );

    /*/ this is the email we get from visitors*/
    $domain_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . 
   "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";

    /*//-->MUST BE 'https://';*/
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.ampproject.org");
    header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: ".$domain_url);

    /*/ For Sending Error Use this code /*/
    if(!mail("rob@webifex.co.uk" , "Site Enquiry" , "email: $name <br/> 
   name: $name" , "From: $name\n ")){
        header("HTTP/1.0 412 Precondition Failed", true, 412);

        echo json_encode(array('errmsg'=>'There is some error while sending 
   email!'));
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        /*/--Assuming all validations are good here--*/
        header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow- 
   Source-Origin");   

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

            echo json_encode(array('successmsg'=>$_POST['name'].'My success 
  message. [It will be displayed shortly(!) if with redirect]'));
        die();
    }
}?>
```

Comment: What is this question even about? How does any of this relate to what you're doing?

Comment: Its about using the amp-form and why it does not work in the amp cache

Comment: Sounds like a question for an AMP specific forum or chat room as unless you can give us a minimal, self-contained example we can test it's anyone's guess as to what's wrong. Form submission to what? From where?

Comment: I thought I was ... https://www.ampproject.org/support/developer/

Comment: That's the documentation. What are you doing that's having a problem? You need to include *that* in your question as code, not as external links.

Comment: I was giving the documentation that says post on stackoverflow using amp-html tag , so i have. I am using the standard AMP form which works perfectly on my domain but NOT in the amp cache. this is detailed in my updated question. not sure what else I can give.?

Comment: Again, what form? Without code we can't really say, and external links to your site don't count as code.

Comment: Updated with code

Comment: I am also seeing The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value '*.ampproject.org'. Origin 'https://article-webiflex-co-uk.cdn.ampproject.org' is therefore not allowed access. but not sure why

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the error message disappeared but I was left with the below new error

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value '*.ampproject.org'. Origin 'article-webiflex-co-uk.cdn.ampproject.org'; is therefore not allowed access.

It would seem that using wilcard *.ampproject.org' produces this error so I have replaced and is working now,